# Image URL Path on server not rendered in normal window but in Incognito it is

Tags: image, reactjs, google-chrome, path

I have an unusual problem that I can't wrap my head around and figure what is causing this and how to tackle it.

I've created a webpage that allows image uploads to the server! After the user uplaoded an image the host of the page receives an e-mail with the path to the uploaded image - really straight forward.

In the e-mail for instance a url like this is coming in.

> https://www.something.com/uploads/FB_IMG_1525868856883.jpg

I can open that in Safari on Mac, I can open that in some cases in Chrome Incogntio, but it never renders in Internet Explorer or normal Chrome Window (in Incognito it does)

[image]

In the image you see something weird happening. In Incognito a different source is rendered than in a normal chrome window. (this is btw. not a caching issue)

you also see the page-title of the actual website resolved in the normal window, but not in incognito.

Why is that happening? What could cause that? is that some server setting? Some react setting I have to set?

Comment: Its likely your browser has cached it.. can you go to the network tab of the dev tools, check disable cache and then reload

Comment: I know you don't need enabled JavaScript in your browser to load an image, but in your left console you have the following message "_You need to enable JavaScript to run this app_". Anyhow, you can make sure your JavaScript is enabled.

Comment: 1.) My javascript is enabled.
2.) The funny thing is it happens also on other machines in chrome. In Safari, Firefox it works. Also in chrome incognito. And I've cleared the entire cache of Chrome Brow.ser

Comment: Also I'm seeing AdBlock in your extensions list. Can you please try to disable all the extensions (in normal Chrome, not incognito)? Here you can turn them off temporary: `chrome://extensions/`

Comment: Also it's a good idea, to share the image's request headers from the both modes - normal and incognito. You can get the headers from Chrome console's Network tab.

Comment: @matt did you try to disable the extensions temporarily? And can you give us the headers too?

Comment: @matt, are you using any service workers as well?

Answer (score 2):

I'm posting this in case someone else runs into it as well. I ran into this same issue where 500 kept happening for me and I knew it was not the extensions.

**What fixed it for me:**

1. Open Developer Tools in Chrome
2. Navigate to Applications Tab
3. Click "Clear Storage
4. Click Clear Site Data

Answer (score 1):

As [Nitish Phanse](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5298398/nitish-phanse) said, it is because the page is cached. **Turning off browser caching will solve it**.

I faced a similar problem, when any of the changes in CSS were not being reflected in the webpage, because the cached version was being used by chrome. However, the changes were visible in other browsers and devices. Turning off caching in chrome solved this problem for me.

I prefer to use incognito mode when developing website because when browsing normally the files are cached, thus, not reflecting the changes you made. When you use incognito mode, fresh cache and cookies are stored and the cache and cookies are disposed when you close the incognito window. Another plus point of using incognito mode for testing is that, it disables all the plugins, unless you explicitly enable them.

You might want to check out this question on [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Does-incognito-mode-on-Chrome-use-the-cache-that-was-previously-stored) for further details on why to use incognito mode when developing websites.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you use quite amount of Chrome plugins. In Incognito-mode those are disabled by default. Try remove/disable AdBlock etc. stuff which blocks scripts and disallow them from running.

Makes quite a lot sense why they run in other browsers too.

I strongly recommend to **NOT** use plugins when you do web development. You might see different kind of behaviour with same code as user who do not use them. *Only use this approach if you especially wan't to develop under certain conditions.*

Answer (score 0):

As most people suggest, it definitely sounds like a caching issue. Incognito doesn't load the page with cache. You could ctrl+f5 the page (reload without chache) and see if it still does it. If the caching itself proves to be an issue, you could add a ghost/phantom string (I don't know if that's the actual correct terminology). Basically you add,

```
<?php echo '?'.date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); ?>
```

at the end CSS or JavaScript import (whatever may cause the issue). I.e,

```
<script src="/js/regexps.js<?php echo '?'.date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); ?>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

What this does, is that it will prevent people from caching your file, since the name of that file will change by the second. This way, you make sure that if you make changes to files that are often cached, that everyone gets the uncached changes as you update your CSS/JavaScript or whatever. This is very useful for files where you make JavaScript check for instance, in case you make changes to some regex etc.